# ABA-issue for never-free environment

Tags: c++, c, lock-free

I have some confusion about ABA-problem for lock free algorithms. I understand the basic wikipedia example and have no problems with it. I would like to clarify the following question:

Suppose both my lock free queue and its users ***never free memory*** allocated for its internal nodes during lifetime of the queue (I am talking about C/C++). So, if I understand it correctly, in such setup the algorithm will always get unique pointers for its allocated nodes, hence the ABA-problem disappears and I can just ignore the tagged pointers solution and simply Compare-And-Swap the pointers.

Is it correct?

Thanks

Comment: You'd need to never reuse the same node pointer (i.e. after adding a node, you can never remove it and add it elsewhere). This doesn't seem like a realistic restraint because it would quickly lead you to run out of memory.

Comment: You also cannot reuse the memory without `free()`ing it (e.g. by passing the pointer back to a producer in a producer-consumer situation). So you have a memory leak, which is generally considered unacceptable.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. It's more of theoretical setup to understand the ABA-problem, so memory leaks can be ignored.

Comment: It's not specifically about freeing but about remove and add back. If you never remove and then add the same node, you're in the clear. But that's not realistic. In the real world you either handle the ABA problem or your setup doesn't let it happen in some other means. Like, for instance, you never remove and add from the same threads, have a relatively long delay between remove and re-add, and probably don't care about processing the same node twice one in long while.